# JQuery event .on('click' not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The JQuery event on click is not firing with the following code:

core.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.login-form-input').on('click', function(){
        alert("s");
        $('#login-description').css({color: #000;}).fadeIn(1000);
    alert("s");
    });  
}
```

index.php

http://pastebin.com/khHZS3HN

Comment: i think this should be string like this: `{color: "#000"}`

Comment: you haven't used onclick in your provide link ??

Comment: @bipen It's a script tag that includes core.js, which is what he's posted above.

Comment: @Andreas : Include jquery before the click function..

Answer (score 2):

You've got this in your page...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That includes your script, core.js, *before* it includes jQuery.  Your script requires jQuery so it should be the other way round...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>
```

Also, as pointed out by reyaner in the question comments, you need quotes around the colour...

```
$('#login-description').css({ color: "#000" }).fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :

**jQuery should be added before the click function and all codes.**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.transit/0.9.9/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>


$(document).on("click", ".login-form-input ", function(e){
    alert("s");
    $('#login-description').css({color: "#000"}).fadeIn(1000);
    alert("s");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
$('#login-description').css({color: #000;}).fadeIn(1000);
```

It should be (-> `{color: "#000"}`):

```
$('#login-description').css({color: "#000"}).fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.login-form-input').click(function () {
    alert("s");
    $('#login-description').css({color: #000;}).fadeIn(1000);

alert("s");
});
```

Comment: bind is for early version of jquery, `on` is the way to go: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.`